# How to complete "StarCraft Master" achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2

In StarCraft2 I have a lot of arcade achievements like "Complete any 10 rounds in StarCraft Master".

I [found](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/StarCraft_Master) that StarCraft Master is a micro map, but I can find it neither in arcade nor in custom maps. So how do I play it and get those achievements?

I am playing HoS on European server.

Comment: It should be in custom maps, but I haven't tried since HotS got released, which is when they changed the system for finding maps a little.

Comment: @scenia, well, I click Custom maps, type "StarCraft Master" in the search line, press Enter, and get about 10 results, but no StarCraft Master in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can find "StarCraft Master" in arcade. Just go to Arcade and put "StarCraft Master" in the search string. Then press play and start game, change nothing. Quite straightforward.
There you can select rounds pressing "Warp". If you quit the game the completed rounds will be saved so you can continue easily.

When you complete any 10 rounds you will get an achievement.